# Trouble Uploading Images Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Tags: admin, image, upload

I have read about various users having trouble with image uploads but I have yet to find a solution to the problem I am having.  In the admin panel, when I am creating a product, I can browse to an image and click open, however, after that the image never shows up.  The upload button is there, but there is nothing to select to upload.

I am on a mac OSX 10.7.5 and using chrome 38.0.2125.111 which runs flash 15,0,0,189

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, or any workaround for it?  I have tried firefox and I have the same issue.

If you need any more information please let me know and I will update.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a browser issue, another possibility is a server related file permission issue. Make sure that your "media" directory has the correct file permissions.

For some servers the file permissions needs to be 666 for files and 777 for directories while for some other servers (especially those with suPHP and SuEXEC), the file permissions need to be 644 for files and 755 for directories.

If you are not sure which of the file permissions you need, you may want to confirm this with your hosting provider.